# Proving a series from zero to infinity is half of a series from minus infinity to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to prove that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}$$ is equivalent to $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}$$

I have played around with it and I know that it is correct but how would I prove this?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to show is that $a_n = a_{-(n+1)}$ i.e.
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} = \frac{(-1)^{-(n+1)}}{(-2(n+1)+1)^3}$$
This is not that hard if you find
$$(-2n-1)^3 = -(2n+1)^3$$
and
$$(-1)^{-(n+1)} = - (-1)^n$$